# Converting Text view to bitmap returns null

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, textview

I am trying to make an image of dynamically added views in my activity.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong, the bitmap returns null for some reason.

Thanks,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("sadasdsadssad");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    tv.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = tv.getDrawingCache();
    ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgQuestion);
    im.setImageBitmap(bm);

}
```

Comment: I was debugging and i found that the Mitmap was null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not add the text view to the the screen. Once you add it, the view height and width will be calculated for rendering and then only view will be drawn and you can get the bitmap out of it.

Do the three things,

1. Add the textview to the parent of that image view.
2. Do a postDelayed to get the bitmap allowing the android system to render the view.
3. Get the bitmap inside postDelayed runnable put in on the image view.

If you do not want the text view not to be shown, use textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); after the fetching the bitmap.

Here is my code for your problem.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

onCreate() of MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv;
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("sadasdsadssad");
    tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ViewGroup rl = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    rl.addView(tv);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            tv.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bm = tv.getDrawingCache();

            ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);

            im.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    },100);


}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks harish, so the problem was that I was not adding my view on screen before converting that to bitmap ?

Comment: Yes. Bitmap wont be generated if rendering did not happen and rendering happens only when you add the view to the current showing layout. Thus, in order to generate bitmap, you need to add the view to current layout. If you don't want that text view anymore after getting that bitmap, you can remove it.

Comment: @Mr_Hmp all the three steps are not needed, just call `View#layout()` to layout your view and then build the drawing cache, no need for adding this view to any parent, no need for `postDelayed`

Comment: thanks this is working. how about more than one textview ? can i do that? convert multiple textview in one bitmap?